# Two-way communication in socket programming using C

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have a small doubt in socket programming. i am able to send my data from client to server and my server processes the data. The o/p of the data processed, I want to send back to my client. So can we "write" the data back to the client using the same socket. I mean a server listens on a port before accepting connection and receiving data, so similarly, do i need to make my client listen to some other port (bind it some other socket) and make my server connect to that socket and transfer the data back. Any kind of example or explanation or references would be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I am also facing this problem. Did you get the answer / sample code ?

Answer (score 16):

Check out [Beej's Network Programming Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) first of all.

The basic screenplay of a server/client connection goes like this:

- Server `listen()`s on a fixed port, with a given socket.
- Client `connect()`s to a the server port; client obtains a socket.
- Server `accept()`s the connection, and `accept()` returns a *new* socket for the connection.
- (Server continues listening on the original port with the original socket.)

For the specific connection with the client, the server `write()`s to the new socket it obtained when `accept()`ing the incoming connection. A busy server will have many, many sockets, but it will only ever need to `bind()` to one port. All connections come in to that one port, but the OS's networking protocol stack separates the data and makes it available at the connection-specific socket.

Comment: It would be better to say that `accept()` *returns* a new socket for the connection

Comment: makes it available at the connection-specific *socket*. there is still *one* server port number, but the OS demultiplexes the incoming packets based on the client ip+port and server ip+port (these 4 and the portocol type(tcp/udp/...) make a connection unique).

Comment: I mean to say that -- Freudian typo :-) Thanks!

Comment: @KerrekSB, I upvoted it by chance.  This is not answering the original question. Right now I am facing the same issue. Where I am able to send data from a (dummy) server to a (dummy) client. But when I try to send data from the client, simply nothing happens. Can you put more light on this?

Comment: @iammilind: Both server and client will have an open file descriptor when they have set up a connection. They can both read from and write to the file descriptor at will.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need a new socket.

A socket is a duplex connection you can send data in both directions and you can even close the socket from one direction (don't want to write anymore) but still send data from the other direction.

Answer (score 3):

Your socket is bi-directional, so there is no need to create another socket. Unless you are using some sort of middleware, such as Pub/Sub, there is no need to create another socket to enable bi-directional communication.

Answer (score 3):

Technically it is right, the socket is duplex and you can send the data to the same socket you read from:

```
   SOCKET s = socket()
   ... //Connect
   int size = receive(s,...);
   //make response 
   send(s, ...);
```

But in practice it depends on what are you going to do. It is possible to hang out socket if you have the following situation:

1. Process 1 sends very big data (<100K) over the socket by one send
   operation
2. Process 2 receives data from 1 by portions and sends small packets to 1 (~20b). It is not a

   confirmations, but some external events.
   The situation goes into hangout, where the sending buffer of the 2 is full and it stops sending confirmations to 1.
   2 and 1 are hanging in their send operations making a deadlock.
   In this case I'd recommend using two sockets. One for read, one for write.

Answer (score 1):

(Late answer, so mainly for anyone else who comes here looking for help)

I recently put up an example client/server application that closely follows Beej's Guide to Network Programming (which was also recommended by Kerrek SB in his answer). If you're looking for a simple working example of client/server communication, maybe this will help:

https://github.com/countvajhula/dummyclientserver

In particular, no, your client does not need to set up a separate listening socket to receive data from the server -- after the server has accepted the connection from the client, the server can simply send data back to the client on the same socket.

Comment: @Andrew well, I can see how you would feel that way and you're right to an extent -- my purpose in answering this was indeed as much to bring visibility to my example app as to answer this specific question (which I nevertheless addressed). But my perspective is that this application would have been very useful to me when I was learning about this stuff, and I hope that it will be so for others who are in a similar stage as the asker of this question as it covers the gamut of basic client/server communication. Additionally, the question did specifically ask for "examples."

Comment: Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully, and note what happened to your other two self-promotional posts. I did not flag this one as spam because at least it contained an answer *somewhere* in the text here.

Comment: I'd hardly call it self-promotion -- that link speaks of "products or websites." I get little out of promoting this, and the reason I even put in the effort to clean up the code and put it up was because I recognized it could be broadly helpful. If an anonymous poster were to point to that code to say, hey, this looks like it would help you -- would you still frown on that? I think I was firmly on-topic and self-promotion even if present was only incidental. But you're entitled to your opinion, as the askers of these questions and those that chance upon these answers are to theirs.

Comment: Additionally, that link mentions "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers." I feel I've quite sincerely adhered to this. And please note again that this is no "product" but in fact just source code.

Comment: It does not matter what you "get" from it; it matters that Stack Overflow is not here to be a repository of links to "stuff", but instead to be a repository of self-contained answers to questions. Promoting something outside of the site does not serve that purpose. That's why *this* answer remained but the others were deleted. Note that too many more inclusions of links to your "sample" will still end up being deleted. You are welcome to agree or disagree, but when it says "products" where you read, what you posted *absolutely counts*.

Comment: Okay, that's fine. Just don't claim that something is self-promotion when it's not. The real issue as you've identified here is favoring self-contained answers, which I can understand why that policy makes sense.

Comment: It *is* self-promotional. It's your project/creation. It's not some disinterested third-party promoting it, which is a slightly different matter.

Comment: What does it matter who is promoting it? It's relevant, on-topic, helpful. Anyway I'm not interested in getting into a flame war with you and arguing just for the sake of arguing. Peace.