# How do I reply asynchronously to a client using sockets in C#?

Tags: c#, serversocket, asyncsocket

I have basically implemented [this asynchronous server socket example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) (and the corresponding client). Using it, I can respond to the client if I follow the example exactly, i.e., if the call to `Send()` the response is in the `ReadCallback()` method.

If, however, I try and send a response outside of here, i.e., in a callback that I've attached to my message processing routine (running in a different thread), I get [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms847615.aspx) error, saying the Socket is not connected. If I try and send a response somewhere else in the `Server` code, say in the `while(true)` loop that's listening to incoming connections, I get the same error.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

**Edit:**

Ok, so I read [Two-way communication in socket programming using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810444/two-way-communication-in-socket-programming-using-c), and I now *think*, according to that answer, that I have to modify the example I linked to so that I reply to the server on the socket  returned by the `accept` process. *My goal is to be able to call `Send()` outside of the receive callback, say from `Main()`, after the client and server are connected.*

Please can someone suggest how I modify the example to achieve what I want? I'm getting thoroughly confused about this, and don't want to create a separate stream if I don't need to (which according to the question I posted, I don't need to...).

Comment: Posting the relevant code snippet before/after your modifications would help us understand better. Talk is good, but usually does not precisely describe the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the connection open then would need to persist the `handler` variable as that is the open socket connection. Then whenever you want to send that connection a message you retrieve its socket and send.

Also, you obviously wouldn't call Shutdown() and Close() on the `handler` variable.

Comment: You, sir, are an absolute hero. That is the easiest mod I've made in weeks. This was definitely a case of "couldn't see the forest for the trees"! (FYI, it was the persistence I was missing).